# can not install nomachine from deb or tar

Tags: dpkg

I have a remote machine in Azure can not rdp to it it is too slow, attempting to install nomachine.  I have tried via tar and deb.  can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```
/usr/NX$ sudo wget https://download.nomachine.com/download/6.3/Linux/nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb
https://download.nomachine.com/download/6.3/Linux/nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb
Resolving download.nomachine.com (download.nomachine.com)... 83.222.232.25
Connecting to download.nomachine.com (download.nomachine.com)|83.222.232.25|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.nomachine.com [following]
https://www.nomachine.com/
Resolving www.nomachine.com (www.nomachine.com)... 80.92.83.99
Connecting to www.nomachine.com (www.nomachine.com)|80.92.83.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb’

/usr/NX$ ls -ial
total 156
1067067 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Dec 11 18:29 .
   1555 drwxr-xr-x 15 root root   4096 Dec 11 18:29 ..
1067068 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 150012 Dec 11 18:29 nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb
nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb                  [   <=>                                                                              ] 146.50K   364KB/s    in 0.4s

2023-12-11 18:29:58 (364 KB/s) - ‘nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb’ saved [150012]


/usr/NX$ sudo dpkg -i nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb: error: 'nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb

dougcwa@Ubuntu-DC:/usr/NX$ ls -ial
total 156
1067067 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Dec 11 18:29 .
   1555 drwxr-xr-x 15 root root   4096 Dec 11 18:29 ..
1067068 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 150012 Dec 11 18:29 nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb
```

Thank You

Comment: You've provided no basic details about your machine; no OS & release, nor *architecture*, so we can only be *generic* in advice. I downloaded that file & asked my system what type of file it was, and it clearly shows it's a HTML source, as you can see yourself if you look..  https://download.nomachine.com/download/8.10/Linux/nomachine_8.10.1_1_amd64.deb may work better for example